# How to retain the same case in the text in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, replace, pattern-matching, regexp-replace

I have a table with columns word and sentence. The idea is to replace the words in the sentence with the link(includes the word itself) if the word is found in the word column. The query below replaces perfectly but since the link is constructed from the temp.word column, the case of the words in the sentence is changed to the case of the words in the word column. Is there a way to retain the same case in the sentence itself?

```
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp
SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation Testing is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'punctuation','automation testing,manual testing,punctuation,automanual testing-testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B-number analysis','B-number analysis table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B-number analysis table','testing B-number analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'Not Matched','testing testing testing' FROM DUAL;

with words(id, word, word_length, search1, replace1, search2, replace2) as (
  select id, word, length(word),
  '(^|\W)' || REGEXP_REPLACE(word, '([][)(}{|^$\.*+?])', '\\\1') || '($|\W)',
  '\1{'|| id ||'}\2',
  '{'|| id ||'}',
  'http://localhost/' || id || '/<u>' || word || '</u>'
  FROM temp
)
, joined_data as (
  select w.search1, w.replace1, w.search2, w.replace2,
    s.rowid s_rid, s.sentence,
    row_number() over(partition by s.rowid order by word_length desc) rn
  from words w
  join temp s
  on instr(UPPER(s.sentence), UPPER(w.word)) > 0
  and regexp_like(s.sentence, w.search1)
)
, unpivoted_data as (
  select S_RID, SENTENCE, PHASE, SEARCH_STRING, REPLACE_STRING,
    row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by phase, rn) rn,
    case when row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by phase, rn)
      = count(*) over(partition by s_rid)
      then 1
      else 0
    end is_last
  from joined_data
  unpivot(
    (search_string, replace_string) 
    for phase in ( (search1, replace1) as 1, (search2, replace2) as 2 ))
)
, replaced_data(S_RID, RN, is_last, SENTENCE) as (
  select S_RID, RN, is_last,
    regexp_replace(SENTENCE, search_string, replace_string,1,0,'i')
  from unpivoted_data
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select n.S_RID, n.RN, n.is_last,
    case when n.phase = 1
      then regexp_replace(o.SENTENCE, n.search_string, n.replace_string,1,0,'i')
      else replace(o.SENTENCE, n.search_string, n.replace_string)
    end
  from unpivoted_data n
  join replaced_data o
    on o.s_rid = n.s_rid and n.rn = o.rn + 1  
)
select s_rid, sentence from replaced_data
where is_last = 1
order by s_rid;
```

```
For example, for id = 1, the sentence is automtestingation Testing is popular kind of testing
After replacement it will be automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>.

The word Testing is replaced with testing(from the temp.word column).
```

The expected outcome is

```
automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>Testing</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  It might be easier to "cheat" and use a `WITH FUNCTION` to answer this question, but that feature was introduced in 12c.

Comment: I am using 11g :-/

Comment: Hi Jon, Do you think of any other approach to achieve this? At the moment, I can't think of other approaches. Any other idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a regular PL/SQL function?

Comment: Yes, I can. What kind of logic to be implemented in the function?

Comment: @MT0, Do you think this is possible? I just need to extend a little bit of our previous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp
SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation TeStInG TEST is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2,'test', 'test' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'punctuation','automation testing,manual testing,punctuation,automanual testing-testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B-number analysis','B-number analysis table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B-number analysis table','testing B-number analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'Not Matched','testing testing testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'^[($','testing characters ^[($ that need escaping in a regular expression' FROM DUAL;
```

**SQL Types**:

```sql
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(20,0);
/
```

**PL/SQL Function**:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION replace_words(
  word_list IN  stringlist,
  id_list   IN  intlist,
  sentence  IN  temp.sentence%TYPE
) RETURN temp.sentence%TYPE
IS
  p_sentence       temp.sentence%TYPE := UPPER( sentence );
  p_pos            PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  p_min_word_index PLS_INTEGER;
  p_word_index     PLS_INTEGER;
  p_start          PLS_INTEGER;
  p_index          PLS_INTEGER;
  o_sentence       temp.sentence%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    p_min_word_index := NULL;
    p_index          := NULL;
    FOR i IN 1 .. word_list.COUNT LOOP
      p_word_index := p_pos;
      LOOP
        p_word_index := INSTR( p_sentence, word_list(i), p_word_index );
        EXIT WHEN p_word_index = 0;
        IF (   p_word_index  > 1
           AND REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR( p_sentence, p_word_index - 1, 1 ), '\w' )
           )
           OR  REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR( p_sentence, p_word_index + LENGTH( word_list(i) ), 1 ), '\w' )
        THEN
           p_word_index := p_word_index + 1;
           CONTINUE;
        END IF;
        IF p_min_word_index IS NULL OR p_word_index < p_min_word_index THEN
          p_min_word_index := p_word_index;
          p_index := i;
        END IF;
        EXIT;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    IF p_index IS NULL THEN
      o_sentence := o_sentence || SUBSTR( sentence, p_pos );
      EXIT;
    ELSE
      o_sentence := o_sentence
                    || SUBSTR( sentence, p_pos, p_min_word_index - p_pos )
                    || 'http://localhost/'
                    || id_list(p_index)
                    || '/<u>'
                    || SUBSTR( sentence, p_min_word_index, LENGTH( word_list( p_index ) ) )
                    || '</u>';
      p_pos := p_min_word_index + LENGTH( word_list( p_index ) );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN o_sentence;
END;
/
```

**Merge**:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH lists ( word_list, id_list ) AS (
    SELECT CAST(
             COLLECT(
               UPPER( word )
               ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) DESC, UPPER( word ) ASC, ROWNUM
             )
             AS stringlist
           ),
           CAST(
             COLLECT(
               id
               ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) DESC, UPPER( word ) ASC, ROWNUM
             )
             AS intlist
           )
    FROM   temp
  )
  SELECT t.ROWID rid,
         replace_words(
           word_list,
           id_list,
           sentence
         ) AS replaced_sentence
  FROM   temp t
         CROSS JOIN lists
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET sentence = src.replaced_sentence;
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM temp;
```

> ```
> ID | WORD                    | SENTENCE                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> -: | :---------------------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | automation testing      | automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>TeStInG</u> http://localhost/2/<u>TEST</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                   
>  2 | testing                 | http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>                                                                                                                                                                  
>  2 | test                    | http://localhost/2/<u>test</u>                                                                                                                                                                            
>  3 | manual testing          | this is an old method of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                                                                
>  4 | punctuation             | http://localhost/1/<u>automation testing</u>,http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>,http://localhost/4/<u>punctuation</u>,automanual http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>-http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
>  5 | B-number analysis       | http://localhost/6/<u>B-number analysis table</u>                                                                                                                                                         
>  6 | B-number analysis table | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis</u>                                                                                                                             
>  7 | Not Matched             | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                     
>  8 | ^[($                    | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> characters http://localhost/8/<u>^[($</u> that need escaping in a regular expression
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29b8ae23647b98abc48be8204ffbafa9)*

Comment: Thanks, MT0. This works perfectly when the records are less. But for the table with 50k records, it utilizes the temp space completely. I added a new temp tablespace as well. It consumes more than 32GB and the temp space goes out of space again. Is there a way to tune this query to improve the performance? Thanks again.

Comment: HI MT0, it would be really helpful if you can help to tune this code. The word should not be replaced if its a substring. For example, the word is "way". If in the sentence there is two-way. The replacement should not happen. And also when the word is a part of the url (https://***"word"***.com). But the replacement should happen when we have way's or way/ or way: or way, or way; etc.,

Comment: @Ana Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [MRE] including the existing function; DDL & DML statements for some sample data that demonstrates **all** issues you are trying to cover; and what you have tried to solve it and the errors that exist. Please also be aware than StackOverflow is not a coding service and we shouldn't be incrementally building your application for you.

Answer (score 0):

While there's certainly a way to do this in a single SQL statement, I think this problem is better solved with a separate function:

```
create or replace function replace_words(p_word varchar2, p_sentence varchar2) return varchar2 is
    v_match_position number;
    v_match_count    number := 0;
    v_new_sentence   varchar2(4000) := p_sentence;
begin
    --Find all matches.
    loop
        --Find Nth case-insensitive match
        v_match_count := v_match_count + 1;
        v_match_position := regexp_instr(
            srcstr     => v_new_sentence,
            pattern    => p_word,
            occurrence => v_match_count,
            modifier   => 'i');

        exit when v_match_position = 0;

        --Insert text, instead of replacing, to keep the original case.
        v_new_sentence :=
            substr(v_new_sentence, 1, v_match_position - 1) || 'http://localhost/2/<u>'||
            substr(v_new_sentence, v_match_position, length(p_word)) || '</u>'||
            substr(v_new_sentence, v_match_position + length(p_word));

    end loop;

    return v_new_sentence;
end;
/
```

Then the SQL query looks like this:

```
select id, word, sentence, replace_words(word, sentence) from temp;
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. But this function has to look for the exact word in the sentence and replace. In your example: the word is 'manual testing' but there is no 'manual testing' in the sentence. If the word was just 'testing' then the replacement is fine.

Comment: @Ana I modified the function to only use a single word.  From your original example, I thought that the word column contained a list of words.  Otherwise, your first example doesn't seem correct

Comment: We need to check all the words in the word column against all the sentences. If any word is found in any of the sentences, we need to replace with the link. For example: We have a word manual testing in the word column, we need to replace manual testing in sentence column. The expected outcome is http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>. The expected outcome for id =5 is http://localhost/1/<u>automation testing</u>, http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>, http://localhost/4/<u>punctuation</u>, automanual http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>-http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>

Comment: @Ana I thought that's what my first version did?  Could you modify the question and list the precise results for each value?

Comment: Your first version was fine. Just that we need to look for the exact word match in the sentence. select replace_words('Manual testing', 'this is an old method of manual testing') from dual; The outcome is this is an old method of http://localhost/2/<u>manual</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> but the expected outcome is "this is an old method of http://localhost/2/<u>manual testing</u>". And also the number in the link is word's respective id. The table consists of 50k records. Should we call this function in the loop to check all the words agianst the sentences?